# Extracting Cucumber Step name at runtime

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I am trying to find out if there is an option to figure out the cucumber step currently getting executed, I am trying to perform certain action depending on the step name.

I can see StepDefinitionMatch class gets the steps, but I am not sure how can I access the steps at runtime. Any help? Adding a snapshot of the call stack if that helps.

```
public StepDefinitionMatch(List<Argument> arguments, StepDefinition stepDefinition, String featurePath, Step step, LocalizedXStreams localizedXStreams) {
    super(arguments, stepDefinition.getLocation(false));
    this.stepDefinition = stepDefinition;
    this.featurePath = featurePath;
    this.step = step;
    this.localizedXStreams = localizedXStreams;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using cucumber-jvm version that is 5.6.0 or latest please follow below solution.
since Reporter class is deprecated you have to implement ConcurrentEventListener and add this class to your TestRunner plugin section.

```
public class StepDetails implements ConcurrentEventListener {
    public static String stepName;

    public EventHandler<TestStepStarted> stepHandler = new EventHandler<TestStepStarted>() {
        @Override
        public void receive(TestStepStarted event) {
            handleTestStepStarted(event);
        }

    };

    @Override
    public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepStarted.class, stepHandler);
    }

    private void handleTestStepStarted(TestStepStarted event) {
        if (event.getTestStep() instanceof PickleStepTestStep) {
            PickleStepTestStep testStep = (PickleStepTestStep)event.getTestStep();
            stepName = testStep.getStep().getText();
        }


    }
}
```

later add this class to your plugin section of cucumberOptions of your runner file

```
@CucumberOptions(dryRun=false,plugin = {"<yourPackage>.StepDetails"})
```

you can get the stepname wherever you want just by calling the stepName variable

```
System.out.println(StepDetails.stepName);
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Not sure why this was not accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a ConcurrentEventListener, setting it in the plugin section:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
...
plugin = {
   ...,
   "com.mycompany.myproduct.AcceptanceStepNameLogger"
}...
```

AcceptanceStepNameLogger example (in this case I only needed to log PickleStepTestStep steps, not hooks):

```
import cucumber.api.*;
import cucumber.api.event.*;

public class AcceptanceStepNameLogger implements ConcurrentEventListener {

    @Override
    public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {

        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepStarted.class, new EventHandler<TestStepStarted>() {
            @Override
            public void receive(TestStepStarted event) {
                if (event.testStep instanceof PickleStepTestStep) {
                    final PickleStepTestStep ev = (PickleStepTestStep) event.testStep;
                    final String args = StringUtils.join(ev.getDefinitionArgument().stream().map(Argument::getValue).toArray(), ",");
                    String testDescription = ev.getStepText() + " : " + ev.getStepLocation();
                    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(args)) {
                        testDescription += (" : args = (" + args + ")");
                    }
                    System.out.println("STARTING STEP: " + testDescription);
                }
            }
        });

        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepFinished.class, new EventHandler<TestStepFinished>() {
            @Override
            public void receive(TestStepFinished event) {
                if (event.testStep instanceof PickleStepTestStep) {
                    PickleStepTestStep ev = (PickleStepTestStep) event.testStep;
                    final String testDescription = ev.getStepText() + " : " + ev.getStepLocation();
                    System.out.println("FINISHED STEP: " + testDescription);
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to get hold of the runtime variables is to use the plugin option. Though it seems like an abuse of the `Reporter` interface to access the `StepDefinitionMatch` variable for **Cucumber version 1.2.5**.

For this create a custom class which implements the `Reporter` interface.

```
public class CustomFormatter implements Reporter{

    public  CustomFormatter() { }

    @Override
    public void before(Match match, Result result) {}

    @Override
    public void result(Result result) {}

    @Override
    public void after(Match match, Result result) {}

    @Override
    public void match(Match match) {
        ThreadLocalStepDefinitionMatch.set((StepDefinitionMatch)match);
    }

    @Override
    public void embedding(String mimeType, byte[] data) {}

    @Override
    public void write(String text) {}
}
```

The `ThreadLocal` class to store the `StepDefinitionMatch` variable.

```
public class ThreadLocalStepDefinitionMatch {

    private static final ThreadLocal<StepDefinitionMatch> threadStepDefMatch = new InheritableThreadLocal<StepDefinitionMatch>();

    private ThreadLocalStepDefinitionMatch() {
    }

    public static StepDefinitionMatch get() {
        return threadStepDefMatch.get();
    }

    public static void set(StepDefinitionMatch match) {
        threadStepDefMatch.set(match);
    }

    public static void remove() {
        threadStepDefMatch.remove();
    }
}
```

The declaration for custom plugin in the runner class

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty", "html:report", "json:reports.json",
        "rerun:target/rerun.txt", "cusform.CustomFormatter" }
```

Finally accessing the `StepDefinitionMatch` variable in the step definition class

```
@When("^user gets count from \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void userGetsCountFromAndStores(String arg) {
        StepDefinitionMatch match = ThreadLocalStepDefinitionMatch.get();
        System.out.println(match.getStepName());
        System.out.println(match.getPattern());
        System.out.println(match.getArguments());
    }
```

The console output gives the following

```
user gets count from "Car1"
^user gets count from "([^"]*)"$
[Car1]
```

---

You are using a pretty old Cucumber version, if you upgrade to Cucumber 2 there will be some changes. The `StepDefinitionMatch` replaced by `PickleTestStep`. The declaration in the runner remains the same. The `ThreadLocal` class change the stored class to `PickleTestStep`.

The custom formatter becomes

```
public class CustomFormatter implements Formatter {

    public CustomFormatter() {}

    private EventHandler<TestStepStarted> stepStartedHandler = new EventHandler<TestStepStarted>() {
        @Override
        public void receive(TestStepStarted event) {
            handleTestStepStarted(event);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
        publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepStarted.class, stepStartedHandler);
    }

    private void handleTestStepStarted(TestStepStarted event) { 
        if(event.testStep instanceof PickleTestStep) {
            ThreadLocalPickleStep.set((PickleTestStep)event.testStep);
        }

    }
}
```

Accessing the StepDefinitionMatch variable in the step definition class

```
@When("^user gets count from \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void userGetsCountFromAndStores(String arg) {

        System.out.println(ThreadLocalPickleStep.get().getStepText());
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalPickleStep.get().getPattern());
        System.out.println(ThreadLocalPickleStep.get().getDefinitionArgument());
    }
```

The output is the same as before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in cucumber 4,

You can Create a event listener class and add it as a plugin at cucumber options:

```java
public class TestStepWatch implements ConcurrentEventListener {
    private EventHandler<TestStepStarted> stepHandler = new EventHandler<TestStepStarted>()
    {
        @Override
        public void receive(TestStepStarted event)
        {
            handleTestStep(event);
        }

        private synchronized void handleTestStep(TestStepStarted event)
        {
            System.out.println("Running step:"+event.testStep.getStepText());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: TestStepStarted only has getCodeLocation, and does not have getStepText.

Answer (score 0):

Below code can be used to get current step method name

```
new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName()
```

Example: 
Given user is on Login page

@Given("^user is on Login page$")
    public void user_is_on_Login_page() throws Throwable {

```
}
```

new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName() => it will return current step method name as "user_is_on_Login_page"

Answer (score 0):

My Cucumber version is 4.7.2 and i wanted to get the step name in my After annotation so that i can use is as fail message while capturing screenshot.i got the Steptext in BeforeStep Annotations and stored it in run time data. I used below code which helped me.

```java
     private int currentStepDefIndex = 0;
    String  currentStepDescr = null;

    @BeforeStep
    public void getCurrentStep(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
        currentStepDefIndex++;

        Field testCase = scenario.getClass().getDeclaredField("testCase");
        testCase.setAccessible(true);

        TestCase Tcs = (TestCase) testCase.get(scenario);
        Field TestSteps = Tcs.getClass().getDeclaredField("testSteps");
        TestSteps.setAccessible(true);

        List<TestStep> teststeps = Tcs.getTestSteps();
        try {
            PickleStepTestStep stepDefs = (PickleStepTestStep) teststeps.get(currentStepDefIndex);
            
               currentStepDescr= stepDefs.getStepText();
                TestContext.getInstance().setValue("CurrentStep", currentStepDescr);
          


            currentStepDefIndex++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ignore.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @After
    public void OnFailureScreenshot(Scenario scenario) {


        currentStepDescr=TestContext.getInstance().getValue("CurrentStep");

        if(scenario.isFailed()){
           //code to capture screenshot and pass currentStepDescription as fail message.
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package runner.steps;

import io.cucumber.plugin.ConcurrentEventListener;
import io.cucumber.plugin.event.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class StepStartedTestListener implements ConcurrentEventListener {
@Override
public void setEventPublisher(EventPublisher publisher) {
    publisher.registerHandlerFor(TestStepStarted.class,this::handleTestStepStarted);
}


private void handleTestStepStarted(TestStepStarted event){
    if (event.getTestStep() instanceof PickleStepTestStep) {
        PickleStepTestStep testStep = (PickleStepTestStep)event.getTestStep();
        String stepName = testStep.getStep().getText();
        stepDetailsPrint(stepName);
    }
}

private void stepDetailsPrint(String stepName){
    String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
    String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[42m";
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println("Step started running at: "+formatter.format(date));
    System.out.println(ANSI_GREEN
            + stepName
            + ANSI_RESET);
}
```

}

And then you need to add this class as a plugin listner in the cucmber options:

```
@CucumberOptions(
    plugin =   { "runner.steps.StepStartedTestListener"},
```

)

Answer (score -1):

Just wait for Cucumber 3.0.0 release, you can access the step names using @AfterStep and @BeforeStep Annotations.

> https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
>   https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/pull/1323

Thanks to Aniket (Coding-Yogi) https://github.com/coding-yogi

Comment: What is the object that needs to be passed to the AfterStep and BeforeStep? The Scenario object getName() returns the description on the scenario.

Comment: How to use `@BeforeStep`?